# Android Http xml error

Tags: java, android, xml, http

I would like to get in string one page xml  response, but my script always shutdown, anybody has an idea what is the problem with that? In the manifest i take:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Code:

```
              String URL = "http://sample.com/test.xml";

             HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
             HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);

    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

    }

    HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();

    try {
        xmlString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
        String s = "2";
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: In the manifest: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Comment: it just shutdown or did it post some logcat response also ?

Comment: With Fatal exeption. Network exeption.

Comment: show crash stacktrace

Comment: You can't do networking on the main thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do networking on the UI Thread (the main thread).

You will need to do your network call on another thread. Use one of the following:

- [ASyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)
- [Loader](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html)
- [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) with Thread

Better yet, do this tutorial:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/index.html

> This tutorial explains the basic tasks involved in connecting to the
>   network, monitoring the network connection (including connection
>   changes), and giving users control over an app's network usage. It
>   also describes how to parse and consume XML data.

Comment: In your openion which is the best function to read xml in :

Android 4.0.4 Ice Cream Sandwich (API level 15)

I mean httpclient or HttpURLConnection?

Comment: imo, HttpUrlConnection, but using this library to wrap it: https://github.com/kevinsawicki/http-request then this library to parse it: https://github.com/novoda/SimpleEasyXmlParser ;-)

Comment: Actually Ill have a lot of data through http thats why I asked. And I dont need any security, so iyo the HttpURLConnection is the winner. Can you tell me why?

Comment: Ease of use really, I have used both and tend to jump from one to the other, I guess it is dependant on the project, more often than not an implementation has already been chosen. Your best asking this question on a forum for discussion not SO

Comment: Is basic spawning of threads via Thread objects also acceptable or are there any caveats I must look out for?

Comment: You don't want to do that as you have no control over them. If you just want basic threads use an `IntentService`